# Context and parameter-specific injection down a Ninject 2 dependency graph

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2

I am interested in creating an instance of an object that implements my `IDistributor` interface using IoC and Ninject.

I have created a concerete implementation (`Distributor`), and all dependent objects/interfaces as required.

The `Distributor` requires a constructor-injected dependency of type `IDistributorContext`.  The concrete type `DistributorContext` can only be created by passing in parameters at runtime.

I'm struggling to decide the best way of implementing this, and also the best way of encapsulating this for exposure to the rest of my application.  At present, I have decided to create a Factory, which is responsible for creating a Ninject Kernel, and resolving dependencies in the `Create` method.  So, my questions are:

1. Is this the preferred solution?  Or would it be better to create a Module that is then exposed to my other assemblies and allow them to instantiate the object?
2. What is the preferred way to create my `Distributor` at runtime?  Noting the runtime parameters that need to be provided to the `DistributorContext` object further down the dependency graph.

The code is:

```
public class DistributorFactory : IDistributorFactory
{
    private const string ContextIdKey = "contextIdKey";
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public DistributorFactory()
    {
        _kernel = CreateKernel();
    }

    public IDistributor Create(int queueId)
    {
        return _kernel.Get<IDistributor>(new Parameter(ContextIdKey, queueId, true));
    }

    private IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IDistributorContext>().To<DistributorContext>().WithConstructorArgument("contextId",
            (context, target) => context.Parameters.First(x => x.Name == QueueIdKey).GetValue(context, target));

        kernel.Bind<IReceiveQueue>().To<ReceiveQueue>();
        kernel.Bind<IDistributor>().To<Distributor>();

        return kernel;
    }
}

public class Distributor : IDistributor
{
    private readonly IReceiveQueue _receiveQueue;
    private readonly IDistributorContext _distributorContext;

    public Distributor(IReceiveQueue receiveQueue, IDistributorContext distributorContext)
    {
        _receiveQueue = receiveQueue;
        _distributorContext = distributorContext;
    }
}

public class DistributorContext: IDistributorContext
{
    private readonly int _contextId;

    public DistributorContext(int contextId)
    {
        _contextId = contextId;
    }
}
```

### Edit:

My application is creating several distributors based on configuration settings stored in XML.  I don't wish to couple my service-based configuration with my distributor implementation, and that is why I went down the route of creating a factory.

An alternative could be to create a `IDistributorConfiguration` and get Ninject to automatically provide a list of `Distributors` to my consuming service.  But then again, I'm not sure that this is any better?

Answer (score 1):

Is is working? Yes defenately.

Is it the prefered solution? Probably not. It's a complicated solution which is normally a hint that there is something wrong in the implementation. But to answer this question you must give information what's the goal behind your implementation. And by goal I do not mean what you want Ninject to do, but rather what your application should do.

Comment: My application wants to create several Distributors dynamically (at runtime, through configuration settings or other means).  I've updated my question to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: @sukhuk I think you missunderstood what I mean. Your goal is defenately not to create a distributor (at least I hope so as this has not value on its own). Your goal is more likely to create something that mediates between some kind of system/components. The distributor is just the way so try to solve this problem. What is missing is information about the problem you want to solve using the distributor.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?: I just say yes it works, that there is a high chance that there is a better solution but there is far to little information to tell how to do better.